# Sharing only to google plus without photo

Tags: android, android-intent

I fount many example where I can share image with installed android app like  this:

```
shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                            .from(getActivity())
                            .setType("image/*")
                            .setStream(imageUris.get(0))
                            .getIntent()             
                            .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But now when I do that, I see complete action using selection: [LINK](http://joxi.ru/4AkORKEf7jOwAq)

Which is unacceptable fro my app. I want share only in goole plus. is it real share without google.photos?
As a solution I find this code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent
            .setAction(imageUris.size() > 1 ? Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
                    : Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setAction(imageUris.size() > 1 ? Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
            : Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {

        ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;

        if (packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")) {
            shareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            Log.e("NEW", "count   0");
        } else if (packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.plus")

                || (packageName
                        .equals("com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.flickr") || packageName
                        .equals("com.twitter.android"))) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,
                    ri.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(imageUris.size() > 1 ? Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
                    : Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            if (packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.plus")) {
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        imageUris);
            } else if (packageName
                    .equals("com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.flickr")) {
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        imageUris);
            } else if (packageName.equals("com.twitter.android")) {
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        imageUris);
            }

            intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri
                    .loadLabel(pm), ri.icon)); 
        }

    }
    // removing google photos like in ios 
    for (int i = 0; i < intentList.size(); i++) {
        String a = intentList.get(i).getComponent().getClassName();
        if (a.contains("com.google.android.apps.photos")) {
            intentList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    // convert intentList to array
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList
            .toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]); 

    Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, String.format(
            context.getString(R.string.format_share_photos),
            imageUris.size()));
    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    context.startActivity(openInChooser);
```

But I can share image (or images) only by facebook and can share image by any of  intentList. Could some body help me or answer to my question. Thanks in advance

ANswer is:

```
Intent shareIntent = null;
            try {
                if (imageUris.size() > 1) {
                    shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*");

                    shareIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
                            "com.google.android.libraries.social.gateway.GatewayActivity");

                    startActivity(shareIntent);
                } else {
                    shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                            .from(getActivity())
                            .setType("image/*")

                            .setStream(imageUris.get(0))
                            .getIntent()
                            .setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
                                    "com.google.android.libraries.social.gateway.GatewayActivity");
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
                }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/" + "profile"
                                + "/posts")));
            }
            break;
```

Comment: I figure it out like this(for many and for one img):